# Accessing SharePoint List from sharepoint hosted add-in returns empty array in results

Tags: 2013, 2010, office-365

I am trying to access SharePoint list from a sharepoint hosted add-in

```
var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));

function getQueryStringParameter(paramName) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");

    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");

        if (singleParam[0] === paramName) {
            return singleParam[1];
        }
    }
}
$.ajax({
        url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/Items?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: function (data) { 
                 console.log(data); 
        },
        error: function (data) {
        }
});
```

This returns itemcount etc, but the results array is empty

Its not bring the items. What should I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `SP Request executor js`. Try below code:

```
'use strict';
    var hostweburl;
    var appweburl;
    // Load the required SharePoint libraries.
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //Get the URI decoded URLs.
        hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));

        // Resources are in URLs in the form:
        // web_url/_layouts/15/resource
        var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";
        // Load the js file and continue to load the page with information about the list items.
        // SP.RequestExecutor.js to make cross-domain requests
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", getListItems);
    });
    // Utilities
    // Retrieve a query string value.
    // For production purposes you may want to use a library to handle the query string.
    function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
        var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
            var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
            if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) return singleParam[1];
        }
    }    
    //Retrieve all of the list items
    function getListItems() {
        var executor;
        // Initialize the RequestExecutor with the app web URL.
        executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
        executor.executeAsync({
            url: appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?@target='" + hostweburl + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            success: getListItemsSuccessHandler,
            error: getListItemsErrorHandler
        });
    }
    //Populate the selectListItems control after retrieving all of the list items.
    function getListItemsSuccessHandler(data) {
        console.log(data)
    }
    function getListItemsErrorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
        console.log("Could not get list items: " + errorMessage);
    }
```

You can also use it without the `sp requestor js` as below:

```
'use strict';
var hostweburl;
var appweburl;
// Load the required SharePoint libraries.
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Get the URI decoded URLs.
    hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));

    // Resources are in URLs in the form:

    getListItems();
});
// Utilities
// Retrieve a query string value.
// For production purposes you may want to use a library to handle the query string.
function getQueryStringParameter(paramToRetrieve) {
    var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
        if (singleParam[0] == paramToRetrieve) return singleParam[1];
    }
}    
//Retrieve all of the list items
function getListItems() {
    $.ajax({
        url: hostweburl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        success: getListItemsSuccessHandler,
        error: getListItemsErrorHandler
});
}
//Populate the selectListItems control after retrieving all of the list items.
function getListItemsSuccessHandler(data) {
    console.log(data)
}
function getListItemsErrorHandler(data, errorCode, errorMessage) {
    console.log("Could not get list items: " + errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: still no results 
{"d":{"results":[]}}

Comment: whats the value in console ?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/Jrn4f    This is what i get in console

Comment: detailed result here
http://i.imgur.com/0qyDhkV.png

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYoSC.png - is the permission correct. Check image

Comment: yeah it did the trick!
is there a way to request permission for all lists? 
Currently it asks me to choose the list when I select trust ap

Comment: @GautamSheth it's not a cross domain call since `appweburl` used in a request (it's the same app web domain). No need to use cross domain library. `$.ajax` will be enough.

Comment: @vignesh https://i.stack.imgur.com/4goZZ.png. I would suggest giving it permssion to web/site collection as in screenshot. It will get access to the whole web and all lists within it.

Comment: @Kai - you are correct. Normal , REST call should work. Updated with another example